# Why doesn't my history save between zsh tabs?

Tags: zsh, history

I do some work in a single terminal tab:

```
> ls
> ps
```

Then I close the terminal, and open a new terminal, and run history

```
> history
    1  history
```

Here is another wierd thing

```
> echo $0
-zsh
> echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

My .zshrc file looks like this

```
setopt inc_append_history
setopt share_history
```

How can I make it preserve the history between tabs?

Comment: The config file is ~/.zshrc, is that a typo or you didn't write the right file? Also is HISTFILE defined?

Comment: In `man zshoptions` : INC_APPEND_HISTORY should be turned off if this SHARE_HISTORY option is in effect.

Comment: HISTFILE is defined, but nothing seems to get written to it. I tried turning off SHARE_HISTORY and had no luck.   I am indeed using ~/.zshrc.  Any other ideas @lolesque ?

Comment: Maybe a access permissions problem, can zsh write in the HISTFILE directory? I have `HISTFILE=~/.history` in my .zshrc

Comment: Looks like it might be something  more fundamental @lolesque.  It looks like I am using some weird bash/zsh hybrid? Is the following a clue?

    > echo $0
    -zsh
    > echo $SHELL
    /bin/bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I had HISTFILE specified in my .zprofile; but I had `setopt share_history` in my `.zshrc`.  I moved the HISTFILE into the .zshrc, prior to the setopt line.  Now it works fine.  Thanks